# What's wrong with my rewrite from jquery to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to rewrite this liquid button https://codepen.io/waaark/pen/VbgwEM , it use jquery.

I want to rewrite it for my react component, but don't know what is wrong:

here is the component code:

```js
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

const getPixelRatio = context => {
    var backingStore =
    context.backingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.backingStorePixelRatio ||
    1;
    
    return (window.devicePixelRatio || 1) / backingStore;
};

const useMove = () => {
    let ref = useRef();
   /*  let msx = 0;
    let msy = 0;
    let mlx = 0;
    let mly = 0; */
    
    /* function mouseSpeed() {
        msx = state.x - state.mouseLastXX;
        msy = state.y - state.mouseLastYY;

        mlx = state.x;
        mly = state.y;

        setTimeout(mouseSpeed, 50);
    } */
    
    const [state, setState] = useState({x: 0, y: 0, mouseDirectionXX:0, mouseDirectionYY:0, mouseSpeedXX:0, mouseSpeedYY:0, mouseLastXX:0, mouseLastYY:0})
    
    const handleMouseMove = e => {
        //e.persist()
        let xx = state.mouseDirectionX;
        let yy = state.mouseDirectionY;
        
        //mouseSpeed();

        if (state.x < e.clientX)
            xx = 1;
        else if (state.x > e.clientX)
            xx = -1;
        else
            xx = 0;
        
        if (state.y < e.clientY)
            yy = 1;
        else if (state.y > e.clientY)
            yy = -1;
        else
            yy = 0;
        
        //rx = (state.x - offset.left);
        //ry = (state.y - offset.top);
            
        setState(state => ({...state, x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY, mouseDirectionXX:xx, mouseDirectionYY:yy}))

        //mouseX = e.clientX;
        //mouseY = e.clientY;
        
        //relMouseX = (mouseX - canvas.offsetLeft);
        //relMouseY = (mouseY - canvas.offsetTop);
        
        //console.log(xx + "///" + yy);

        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    
        return () => window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      }, []);
   
    return {
        mouseX: state.x,
        mouseY: state.y,
        mouseDirectionX: state.mouseDirectionXX,
        mouseDirectionY: state.mouseDirectionYY,
        mouseLastX: state.mouseLastXX,
        mouseLastY: state.mouseLastYY,
        mouseSpeedX: state.mouseSpeedXX,
        mouseSpeedY: state.mouseSpeedYY,
        //relMouseX: state.relMouseXX,
        //relMouseY: state.relMouseYY,
        handleMouseMove,
    }
}

const LiquidButton = () => {
    const {mouseX, mouseY, mouseDirectionX, mouseDirectionY, handleMouseMove} = useMove();
    let ref = useRef();
    let buttonWidth = 240;
    let buttonHeight = 60;
    let points = 8;
    let pointsA = [], pointsB = [];
    let viscosity = 10, mouseDist = 70, damping = 0.05, showIndicators = false;
    
    let relMouseX = 0;
    let relMouseY = 0;
    

    //let canvas = ref.current;

    /* function mouseSpeed() {
        mouseSpeedX = mouseX - mouseLastX;
        mouseSpeedY = mouseY - mouseLastY;

        mouseLastX = mouseX;
        mouseLastY = mouseY;

        setTimeout(mouseSpeed, 50);
        //console.log("AYE");
    }
    mouseSpeed(); */
    

    useEffect(() => {

        let canvas = ref.current;
        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        let canvaspos = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        let offset = { 
            top: canvaspos.top, 
            left: canvaspos.left, 
        };
        let mouseLastX = 0;
        let mouseLastY = 0;
        //mouseDirectionX = 0,
        //mouseDirectionY = 0,
        let mouseSpeedX = 0;
        let mouseSpeedY = 0;

        relMouseX = (mouseX - offset.left);
        relMouseY = (mouseY - offset.top);

        mouseSpeedX = mouseX - mouseLastX;
        mouseSpeedY = mouseY - mouseLastY;

        mouseLastX = mouseX;
        mouseLastY = mouseY;

        //NEW
        

        console.log("mouseX:" + mouseX)
        console.log("mouseLastX: "+ mouseLastX);
        console.log("mouseSpeedX: "+ mouseSpeedX);
        console.log("relMouseX:" + relMouseX)
        console.log("mouseDirectionX: "+ mouseDirectionX);
        

        console.log("mouseY:" + mouseY)
        console.log("mouseLastY: "+ mouseLastY);
        console.log("mouseSpeedY: "+ mouseSpeedY);
        console.log("relMouseY:" + relMouseY)
        console.log("mouseDirectionY: "+ mouseDirectionY);

        
        
    
        function Point(x, y, level) {
            this.x = this.ix = 75+x;
            this.y = this.iy = 75+y;
            this.vx = 0;
            this.vy = 0;
            this.cx1 = 0;
            this.cy1 = 0;
            this.cx2 = 0;
            this.cy2 = 0;
            this.level = level;
          }
    
          Point.prototype.move = function() {
            this.vx += (this.ix - this.x) / (viscosity*this.level);
            this.vy += (this.iy - this.y) / (viscosity*this.level);
    
            var dx = this.ix - relMouseX,
                dy = this.iy - relMouseY;
            var relDist = (1-Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy))/mouseDist);
    
            // Move x
            if ((mouseDirectionX > 0 && relMouseX > this.x) || (mouseDirectionX < 0 && relMouseX < this.x)) {
                if (relDist > 0 && relDist < 1) {
                    this.vx = (mouseSpeedX / 4) * relDist;
                }
            }
            this.vx *= (1 - damping);
            this.x += this.vx;
    
            // Move y
            if ((mouseDirectionY > 0 && relMouseY > this.y) || (mouseDirectionY < 0 && relMouseY < this.y)) {
                if (relDist > 0 && relDist < 1) {
                    this.vy = (mouseSpeedY / 4) * relDist;
                }
            }
            this.vy *= (1 - damping);
            this.y += this.vy;
        };
    
        function addPoints(x, y) {
            pointsA.push(new Point(x, y, 1));
            pointsB.push(new Point(x, y, 2));
        }
        //NEW-END
        
        let ratio = getPixelRatio(context);
        let width = getComputedStyle(canvas)
            .getPropertyValue('width')
            .slice(0, -2);
        let height = getComputedStyle(canvas)
            .getPropertyValue('height')
            .slice(0, -2);
        
        canvas.width = buttonWidth+150;
        canvas.height = buttonHeight+150;
        //canvas.width = width * ratio;
        //canvas.height = height * ratio;
        canvas.style.width = width+`px`;
        canvas.style.height = height+`px`;

        let x = buttonHeight/2;
        for(var j = 1; j < points; j++) {
            addPoints((x+((buttonWidth-buttonHeight)/points)*j), 0);
        }
        addPoints(buttonWidth-buttonHeight/5, 0);
        addPoints(buttonWidth+buttonHeight/10, buttonHeight/2);
        addPoints(buttonWidth-buttonHeight/5, buttonHeight);
        for(var j = points-1; j > 0; j--) {
            addPoints((x+((buttonWidth-buttonHeight)/points)*j), buttonHeight);
        }
        addPoints(buttonHeight/5, buttonHeight);

        addPoints(-buttonHeight/10, buttonHeight/2);
        addPoints(buttonHeight/5, 0);

        let requestId, i = 0;

        const render = () => {
            // Clear scene
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.0)";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // Move points
            for (var i = 0; i <= pointsA.length - 1; i++) {
                pointsA[i].move();
                pointsB[i].move();
            }

            // Create dynamic gradient
        var gradientX = Math.min(Math.max(mouseX - offset.left, 0), canvas.width);
        var gradientY = Math.min(Math.max(mouseY - offset.top, 0), canvas.height);
        var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(gradientX - canvas.width/2, 2) + Math.pow(gradientY - canvas.height/2, 2)) / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(canvas.width/2, 2) + Math.pow(canvas.height/2, 2));

        var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(gradientX, gradientY, 300+(300*distance), gradientX, gradientY, 0);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, '#102ce5');
        gradient.addColorStop(1, '#E406D6');
        
        // Draw shapes
        var groups = [pointsA, pointsB]

        for (var j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
            var points = groups[j];

            if (j == 0) {
                // Background style
                context.fillStyle = '#1CE2D8';
            } else {
                // Foreground style
                context.fillStyle = gradient;
            }

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                var p = points[i];
                var nextP = points[i + 1];
                var val = 30*0.552284749831;

                if (nextP != undefined) {
                    // if (nextP.ix > p.ix && nextP.iy < p.iy) {
                    //  p.cx1 = p.x;
                    //  p.cy1 = p.y-val;
                    //  p.cx2 = nextP.x-val;
                    //  p.cy2 = nextP.y;
                    // } else if (nextP.ix > p.ix && nextP.iy > p.iy) {
                    //  p.cx1 = p.x+val;
                    //  p.cy1 = p.y;
                    //  p.cx2 = nextP.x;
                    //  p.cy2 = nextP.y-val;
                    // }  else if (nextP.ix < p.ix && nextP.iy > p.iy) {
                    //  p.cx1 = p.x;
                    //  p.cy1 = p.y+val;
                    //  p.cx2 = nextP.x+val;
                    //  p.cy2 = nextP.y;
                    // } else if (nextP.ix < p.ix && nextP.iy < p.iy) {
                    //  p.cx1 = p.x-val;
                    //  p.cy1 = p.y;
                    //  p.cx2 = nextP.x;
                    //  p.cy2 = nextP.y+val;
                    // } else {

                        p.cx1 = (p.x+nextP.x)/2;
                        p.cy1 = (p.y+nextP.y)/2;
                        p.cx2 = (p.x+nextP.x)/2;
                        p.cy2 = (p.y+nextP.y)/2;

                        context.bezierCurveTo(p.x, p.y, p.cx1, p.cy1, p.cx1, p.cy1);
                    //  continue;
                    // }

                    // context.bezierCurveTo(p.cx1, p.cy1, p.cx2, p.cy2, nextP.x, nextP.y);
                } else {
nextP = points[0];
                        p.cx1 = (p.x+nextP.x)/2;
                        p.cy1 = (p.y+nextP.y)/2;

                        context.bezierCurveTo(p.x, p.y, p.cx1, p.cy1, p.cx1, p.cy1);
                }
            }

            // context.closePath();
            context.fill();
        }

        if (showIndicators) {
            // Draw points
            context.fillStyle = '#000';
            context.beginPath();
            for (var i = 0; i < pointsA.length; i++) {
                var p = pointsA[i];

                context.rect(p.x - 1, p.y - 1, 2, 2);
            }
            context.fill();

            // Draw controls
            context.fillStyle = '#f00';
            context.beginPath();
            for (var i = 0; i < pointsA.length; i++) {
                var p = pointsA[i];

                context.rect(p.cx1 - 1, p.cy1 - 1, 2, 2);
                context.rect(p.cx2 - 1, p.cy2 - 1, 2, 2);
            }
            context.fill();
        }
            
            requestId = requestAnimationFrame(render);
        };
        
        render();

        return () => {
            cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
        };
    });
  return (
      <div>
    <canvas ref={ref} style={{ width: '390px', height: '210px' }} >
        <a href="#" className="btn-liquid">
            <span className="inner">Press Button</span>
        </a>
    </canvas>
    <div className="mouseArea">
      Hook
      <div className="mouseInfo">
        The current mouse position is ({mouseX}, {mouseY}) <br />
       Mouse Direction is ({mouseDirectionX}, {mouseDirectionY}) <br />
       {/* Mouse Last ({mouseLastX}, {mouseLastY}) <br /> */}
       {/* Mouse Speed ({mouseSpeedX}, {mouseSpeedY}) <br /> */}
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LiquidButton;
```

i tried to calculate the mouse speed and mouse direction, but still confuse where to put the code.When I console log the value, the mouse position, mouse speed and mouse last position are the same value

Comment: At what stage during the process of creating this, did you notice that there was an issue? And what error are you seeing when debugging? May be able to pin point the error a little quicker.

Comment: during the running stage, no error, just not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
let pointsA = [];
let pointsB = [];
let $canvas = null;
let canvas = null;
let context = null;
// let  vars = null;
let points = 8;
let viscosity = 20;
let mouseDist = 70;
let damping = 0.05;
let showIndicators = false;
let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;
let relMouseX = 0;
let relMouseY = 0;
let mouseLastX = 0;
let mouseLastY = 0;
let mouseDirectionX = 0;
let mouseDirectionY = 0;
let mouseSpeedX = 0;
let mouseSpeedY = 0;

function mouseDirection(e) {
  if (mouseX < e.pageX)
    mouseDirectionX = 1;
  else if (mouseX > e.pageX)
    mouseDirectionX = -1;
  else
    mouseDirectionX = 0;

  if (mouseY < e.pageY)
    mouseDirectionY = 1;
  else if (mouseY > e.pageY)
    mouseDirectionY = -1;
  else
    mouseDirectionY = 0;

  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;

  relMouseX = (mouseX - $canvas.offset().left);
  relMouseY = (mouseY - $canvas.offset().top);
}

function mouseSpeed() {
  mouseSpeedX = mouseX - mouseLastX;
  mouseSpeedY = mouseY - mouseLastY;

  mouseLastX = mouseX;
  mouseLastY = mouseY;

  setTimeout(mouseSpeed, 50);
}

mouseSpeed();

function initButton(button) {
  // Get button
  // var button = $('.btn-liquid');
  var buttonWidth = button.width();
  var buttonHeight = button.height();

  // Create canvas
  $canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
  button.append($canvas);

  canvas = $canvas.get(0);
  canvas.width = buttonWidth + 100;
  canvas.height = buttonHeight + 100;
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Add points

  var x = buttonHeight / 2;
  for (let j = 1; j < points; j++) {
    addPoints((x + ((buttonWidth - buttonHeight) / points) * j), 0);
  }
  addPoints(buttonWidth - buttonHeight / 5, 0);
  addPoints(buttonWidth + buttonHeight / 10, buttonHeight / 2);
  addPoints(buttonWidth - buttonHeight / 5, buttonHeight);
  for (let j = points - 1; j > 0; j--) {
    addPoints((x + ((buttonWidth - buttonHeight) / points) * j), buttonHeight);
  }
  addPoints(buttonHeight / 5, buttonHeight);

  addPoints(-buttonHeight / 10, buttonHeight / 2);
  addPoints(buttonHeight / 5, 0);
  // addPoints(x, 0);
  // addPoints(0, buttonHeight/2);

  // addPoints(0, buttonHeight/2);
  // addPoints(buttonHeight/4, 0);

  // Start render
  renderCanvas();
}

function addPoints(x, y) {
  pointsA.push(new Point(x, y, 1));
  pointsB.push(new Point(x, y, 2));
}

function Point(x, y, level) {
  this.x = this.ix = 50 + x;
  this.y = this.iy = 50 + y;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.cx1 = 0;
  this.cy1 = 0;
  this.cx2 = 0;
  this.cy2 = 0;
  this.level = level;
}

Point.prototype.move = function() {
  this.vx += (this.ix - this.x) / (viscosity * this.level);
  this.vy += (this.iy - this.y) / (viscosity * this.level);

  var dx = this.ix - relMouseX,
    dy = this.iy - relMouseY;
  var relDist = (1 - Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy)) / mouseDist);

  // Move x
  if ((mouseDirectionX > 0 && relMouseX > this.x) || (mouseDirectionX < 0 && relMouseX < this.x)) {
    if (relDist > 0 && relDist < 1) {
      this.vx = (mouseSpeedX / 4) * relDist;
    }
  }
  this.vx *= (1 - damping);
  this.x += this.vx;

  // Move y
  if ((mouseDirectionY > 0 && relMouseY > this.y) || (mouseDirectionY < 0 && relMouseY < this.y)) {
    if (relDist > 0 && relDist < 1) {
      this.vy = (mouseSpeedY / 4) * relDist;
    }
  }
  this.vy *= (1 - damping);
  this.y += this.vy;
};

function renderCanvas() {
  // rAF
  // rafID =
  requestAnimationFrame(renderCanvas);

  // Clear scene
  context.clearRect(0, 0, $canvas.width(), $canvas.height());
  context.fillStyle = '#fff';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, $canvas.width(), $canvas.height());

  // Move points
  for (var i = 0; i <= pointsA.length - 1; i++) {
    pointsA[i].move();
    pointsB[i].move();
  }

  // Create dynamic gradient
  var gradientX = Math.min(Math.max(mouseX - $canvas.offset().left, 0), $canvas.width());
  var gradientY = Math.min(Math.max(mouseY - $canvas.offset().top, 0), $canvas.height());
  var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(gradientX - $canvas.width() / 2, 2) + Math.pow(gradientY - $canvas.height() / 2, 2)) / Math.sqrt(Math.pow($canvas.width() / 2, 2) + Math.pow($canvas.height() / 2, 2));

  var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(gradientX, gradientY, 300 + (300 * distance), gradientX, gradientY, 0);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, '#102ce5');
  gradient.addColorStop(1, '#E406D6');

  // Draw shapes
  var groups = [pointsA, pointsB]

  for (var j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
    var points = groups[j];

    if (j === 0) {
      // Background style
      context.fillStyle = '#1CE2D8';
    } else {
      // Foreground style
      context.fillStyle = gradient;
    }

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      var p = points[i];
      var nextP = points[i + 1];
      // var val = 30*0.552284749831;

      if (nextP !== undefined) {
        // if (nextP.ix > p.ix && nextP.iy < p.iy) {
        //  p.cx1 = p.x;
        //  p.cy1 = p.y-val;
        //  p.cx2 = nextP.x-val;
        //  p.cy2 = nextP.y;
        // } else if (nextP.ix > p.ix && nextP.iy > p.iy) {
        //  p.cx1 = p.x+val;
        //  p.cy1 = p.y;
        //  p.cx2 = nextP.x;
        //  p.cy2 = nextP.y-val;
        // }  else if (nextP.ix < p.ix && nextP.iy > p.iy) {
        //  p.cx1 = p.x;
        //  p.cy1 = p.y+val;
        //  p.cx2 = nextP.x+val;
        //  p.cy2 = nextP.y;
        // } else if (nextP.ix < p.ix && nextP.iy < p.iy) {
        //  p.cx1 = p.x-val;
        //  p.cy1 = p.y;
        //  p.cx2 = nextP.x;
        //  p.cy2 = nextP.y+val;
        // } else {

        p.cx1 = (p.x + nextP.x) / 2;
        p.cy1 = (p.y + nextP.y) / 2;
        p.cx2 = (p.x + nextP.x) / 2;
        p.cy2 = (p.y + nextP.y) / 2;

        context.bezierCurveTo(p.x, p.y, p.cx1, p.cy1, p.cx1, p.cy1);
        //  continue;
        // }

        // context.bezierCurveTo(p.cx1, p.cy1, p.cx2, p.cy2, nextP.x, nextP.y);
      } else {
        nextP = points[0];
        p.cx1 = (p.x + nextP.x) / 2;
        p.cy1 = (p.y + nextP.y) / 2;

        context.bezierCurveTo(p.x, p.y, p.cx1, p.cy1, p.cx1, p.cy1);
      }
    }

    // context.closePath();
    context.fill();
  }

  if (showIndicators) {
    // Draw points
    context.fillStyle = '#000';
    context.beginPath();
    for (let i = 0; i < pointsA.length; i++) {
      // var p = pointsA[i];

      context.rect(p.x - 1, p.y - 1, 2, 2);
    }
    context.fill();

    // Draw controls
    context.fillStyle = '#f00';
    context.beginPath();
    for (let i = 0; i < pointsA.length; i++) {
      // var p = pointsA[i];

      context.rect(p.cx1 - 1, p.cy1 - 1, 2, 2);
      context.rect(p.cx2 - 1, p.cy2 - 1, 2, 2);
    }
    context.fill();
  }
}


const StaticLiquidButton = ({
  className,
  liquidBtnRef,
  href
}) => ( <
  a href = {
    href
  }
  className = "btn-liquid"
  ref = {
    liquidBtnRef
  } >
  <
  span class = "inner" >
  Liquid button ?
  <
  /span> <
  /a>
);

StaticLiquidButton.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};


const LiquidButton = () => {
  const liquidBtnRef = React.useRef()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const button = liquidBtnRef.current;
    initButton($(button));
    $(document).on('mousemove', mouseDirection);
    return () => {
      $(document).off('mousemove', mouseDirection)
    }
  },[])
  return (
    <StaticLiquidButton
      className="TeslaAppUI-LiquidButton"
      href="http://waaark.com"
      liquidBtnRef={liquidBtnRef}
    />
  )
}


function App() {
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    LiquidButton / >
    <
    /div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-liquid {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 60px;

    border-radius: 27px;

    color: #fff;
    font: 700 14px/60px "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-liquid .inner {
    position: relative;

    z-index: 2;
}

.btn-liquid canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    right: -50px;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: -50px;

    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.min.js" integrity="sha512-ssNhh7jlzc+K93ckIlSXFHHz6fSFv0l619WOv8xbFNRbFOujbasb42LVMOggDrQR1ScJncoWb+KAJx1uF3ipjw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Good Luck...

Comment: but i don't want to use jquery, that's the problem. I want to write that jquery button into pure react / js. But thanks

Comment: Hi @smals,  without `jquery` you'll not have utils such as `.width(), .heigith(), $("<canvas></canvas>)` etc..   If you can remove `jquery` from. your Codepen snippet;  I can set it up without `jQuery` on Stack Overflow :)